# Linode instance SSL installation and auto DNS assignment with Cloudflare

Tags: dns, terraform, ss

Here it’s my implementation.

```
resource "linode_instance" "server" {
  count  = 1
  label  = "server-${count.index}"
  region = "ap-west"
  image  = "linode/ubuntu21.10"
  type   = "g6-nanode-1"
  tags   = ["prod"]
  root_pass      = var.linode_instance_root_password
  stackscript_id = linode_stackscript.nodejs_script.id
  stackscript_data = {
   "dns" = "server-${count.index}"
   "email" = var.ssl_certificate_email
  }
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "server" {
  zone_id = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  name    = "server-${count.index}"
  count   = "${length(linode_instance.server)}"
  value   = "${linode_instance.server[count.index].ip_address}"
  ttl     = 1
  type    = "A"
}
```

I can create the certificate.pem and private key.pem files with certbot in Linode Script however since I create the DNS resource after the Linode instance creation it’s not possible to do that. What are the best practices for this?

Note: I've also tried to create wildcard certification ([as explained in here](https://marcincuber.medium.com/lets-encrypt-generating-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-certbot-ae1c9484c101)) but I'm not sure how can I copy the certificate files to my servers?

**Update**

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install certbot
# <UDF name="dns" label="System Package to Install" example=“server" default="">
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --non-interactive --agree-tos -m ...@mail.com -d $DNS
```

Comment: And what would happen if you were to try creating certificates? Would the code fail?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I create the certificates. Normally, I was using `certbot` and installing directly to the instance. But here since the domain record is not created yet, I'm not sure how it will work. Here it is some details, about the problem I've asked.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1096137/how-to-lets-encrypt-wildcard-ssl-certificate-on-multiple-servers

There's also an option to pass the data with Stack Script.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/linode/linode/latest/docs/resources/stackscript

Nothing worked yet.

Comment: @MarkoE I've updated the question and included the stack script data script and stackscript_data under the linode-instance

Comment: Does an instance get created when you set `count = 0`?

Comment: No, actually I make it > 0. I have forgotten while testing, assume that is > 0.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking you need an SSH key. In this case, you might use Terraform output to generate the certificate using the `certbot`.

Comment: Do you plan on having more than one server and server DNS record?

Comment: Yes, I plan to have multiple servers for different regions as I described here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1096137/how-to-lets-encrypt-wildcard-ssl-certificate-on-multiple-servers

Comment: Wouldn't the servers have different FQDN in that case? Copying the certificate over wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I use a wildcard certificate, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ok, and a wildcard record can be created with the current CloudFlare resource from the question? How would the command for the certbot look then? I am asking because I am trying to figure out the answer to this question. :)

Comment: Instead of certbot I've followed the following:

https://itnext.io/lets-encrypt-certs-with-terraform-f870def3ce6d

I'm able to create SSL certificates now and put the files to Linode object storage. 

However, I'm still not sure if I just download that files on my Linode script (where I install packages to my Ubuntu and start the Nodejs Express server), would it work correctly.